# Regarding jquery code snippet help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Regarding the below code snippet i understand the bit but i have few confusion like

```
$(this).children().contents().wrap('<div>').parent().slideUp(function() {    
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

1) `children().contents()` what it does.
2) `wrap('<div>')` what is wrapping and why div is required.
3) which one is parent `parent()` tr parent is table
4) what is the functionality of `closest()` how `closest('tr')` refer current tr?

i just do not understand the above line like

### full code

```
<table border="1" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="test">
<tr>
    <td><b>First Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Address</b></td>
    <td><b>Town</b></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Town</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Town</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Town</td>
</tr>
```

```
$('#test tr:not(:first)').click(function() {           
    $(this).css("background-color","red");  

    $(this).children().contents().wrap('<div>').parent().slideUp(function() {    
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you read jQuery documentation? the answer to 1), 2) and 4) should be there.

Comment: I think you should read the jQuery API documentation. Any answers you'll get here will highly likely link to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `children().contents()` will return the content of each `<td>` for the clicked `<tr>`. According to your example, all `tds` contain text and so an array of `TextNode` will be returned.
2. `wrap('<div>')` it will wrap each text with a  tag. `<div>` is not "required", it's a what you are wrapping your text with.
3. `parent()` it refers to the `<div>` since `<div>` is the parent for the content after wrapping.
4. `closest()` simply return the nearest `<tr>` which is the `<tr>` being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

contents => http://api.jquery.com/contents/

so it will get all textNodes in your example ( Frist Name, Last name and so on)

then you are wrapping those textNodes with a div so it actually becomse:

first name and so on, then you go up to that div with `.parent()` and then you slide up, after its done you remove the closest tr from the `div` you created.

a tip is to use firefox (with firebug) or chrome or any browser that has a console, it will help you debug codes like this in the future super fast and super easy.